Why does my Glue Crawler exclude pattern not apply?
I know that this has been asked before. But I have spent hours trying to get this to work.
I have a directory structure like:
- datalake
--- datasets
----- foo
------- 00001.json
------- 00002.json
------- latest.json
----- bar
------- 00001.json
------- latest.json

my include path looks like
s3:<bucket_name>/datalake/datasets/
i want to exclude things that are not latest.jsons
I have tried everything under the sun.
**0*
**/0**
*/0*
*0*
**0**

and many others.
Without fail, my crawler catalogs every .json.
I am checking the results of my crawl with Athena.
Am I seriously getting the exclude pattern wrong? Or am I somehow thinking about this entire thing the wrong way and my pattern is irrelevant?

i think that the answer has something to do with the partioning of my files among s3 buckets. on the right-hand-side of the crawler overview, the exclude pattern seems to be updating the partitions

For me, the answer ended up being related to the fact that I was using Athena to look at the updated catalog. According to this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/troubleshooting-athena.html#troubleshooting-athena-data-file-issues
Athena will not respect the exclusion of glue files.

UPDATED
It seems that using exclude pattern **/*[!latest.json] will not work as per mentioned by OP due to single character matching.

Remove your exclude patterns
Use s3:<bucket_name>/datalake/datasets/**latest.json as your overall include path


thanks for the reply. same thing. for the record, from, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html#crawler-data-stores-exclude the brackets seem to be more of a single character match. "Brackets [ ] create a bracket expression that matches a single character of a name component out of a set of characters. For example, [abc] matches a, b, or c"

@rictuar, can you try removing the exclude pattern and use the include pattern above instead?

i am confused, to me, it looks like there is no such thing as an include pattern. Rather, there is an overall include path, with exclude patterns only
